# Catching an exception for input and output file

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, fstream

I open two files, one input and one output. I'd like to handle exceptions for both of them, so by looking at some examples, I made this:

```
std::ifstream readFile;
readFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
//set the flags for stream bits that indicate failure if ON
std::ofstream writeFile;
writeFile.exceptions (std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);


try{
    readFile.open(inputFileName);
    writeFile.open(outputFileName);

    function(readFile, writeFile);

    readFile.close();
    writeFile.close();
}
catch(std::ifstream::failure &readErr) {
    std::cerr << "\n\nException occured when reading a file\n"
              << readErr.what()
              << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
catch(std::ofstream::failure &writeErr) {
    std::cerr << "\n\nException occured when writing to a file\n"
         << writeErr.what()
         << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

This seems like a reasonable solution, but I get a warning:

```
warning: exception of type 'std::ios_base::failure' will be caught [enabled by default]
     catch(std::ofstream::failure &writeErr) {
     ^
```

The code does it's thing, but I'm still interested in improving my code. Where have I wronged?

Comment: Always catch exceptions by const reference: `catch(const std::ofstream::failure &writeErr) {`

Comment: How come, does it make a difference?

Comment: Both the bits your setting and the exceptions your catching are not in `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`. They're rooted in [**`std::ios_base`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) in the base-hierarchy of *both*. I.e. `std::ifstream::failure` and `std::ofstream::failure` are **both**  actually `std::ios_base::failure`. So you're catching the same exception *twice*.

Comment: Isn't there a way to separate them?

Comment: I've never tried, and would be honestly interested in seeing of there is such a mechanism. My initial reaction would be no, not without nesting the  ops in their own try-catch blocks. (which would need to be done in `function` in your code).

Comment: But that makes it a general exception, not really telling which file caused it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't. The typedef of `std::ifstream::failure` and `std::ofstream::failure` are both defined to be `std::ios_base::failure`.

The best thing you could do is wrap the individual calls with try-catch:

```
try
{
  readFile.open(inputFileName);
}
catch(std::ifstream::failure &readErr) 
{
}

try
{
   writeFile.open(outputFileName);
}
catch(std::ofstream::failure &writeErr) 
{
}
```

Or check the state of the streams individually in the catch block to see who failed.

Comment: I think that in the second catch block, you meant "std::ofstream::failure &writeErr", no?  It's possible I'm misunderstanding you here, so I'm asking to make sure I'm not entirely missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to handle exceptions from the two files separately would be to catch the exception and then check the failbit on the streams to determine which of them that failed:

```
try
{
    readFile.open(inputFileName);
    writeFile.open(outputFileName);

    function(readFile, writeFile);

    readFile.close();
    writeFile.close();
}
catch (const std::ios_base::failure &err)
{
    if (readFile.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "\n\nException occured when reading a file\n"
                  << readErr.what()
                  << std::endl;
    }
    if (writeFile.fail())
    {
        std::cerr << "\n\nException occured when writing to a file\n"
                  << writeErr.what()
                  << std::endl;
    }

    return -1;
}
```